# Video playback stops working, and then starts working again

Tags: video, driver, macos

This has happened me a few times, most recently yesterday and is weird. For some reason video playback stops working. I then wait a few hours/use the computer for other things, let it sleep a couple of times etc - and suddenly video playback works again.

More details: I tried to watch a video in Firefox but it refused to play (properly - it played a few seconds, 3-5, and then stopped). I could jump around in the video and the frame at at position would be displayed as a still frame but it wouldn't play.

I tried different sites, in private as well as regular windows, restarting Firefox etc - all to no avail. I also tried in Chrome, Safari and Brave browser - all with the same result - no video playback. Except for video, the browsers worked normal. Next I tried VLC and Quicktime Player, but not even they would play video, it was just black and stuck at 00:00.

After that I just used the computer for other stuff for a few hours, let it sleep over night - and now when I try to play the same videos I tried yesterday it works as usual.

My guess is that something with the video driver hung or crashed and that it restarts itself from time to time.

This was not the first time I experienced this, it happens a couple of times per year or so. It might be connected with that I force quitted a couple of Firefox and Chrome tabs just before I tried to play video because the computer had slowed down to a crawl due to very high memory pressure (which was natural, I ran something very demanding).

This is an Intel-Mac with Ventura.

Would be very interesting and useful to know what could be behind this and if there is something you could kill/restart to make video playback work again under "controlled circumstances".